# Solr 6 fail to index images

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm trying to index images on SOLR, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: [doc=5b36cb2b78072e41] Error adding field 'media_black_point'='(0.012054443, 0.012496948, 0.010314941)' msg=For input string: "(0.012054443"
```

It looks like it's a problem of field types, but these fields are extracted automatically. I'm forgetting some additional configuration?

I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the answer from the solr mailing list:

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201606.mbox/%3C7bb4ad8a-1e66-8442-abe3-5181b67ea24c@elyograg.org%3E

The linked issue has an example method for cleaning up the content prior to indexing:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8017?focusedCommentId=15256432&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15256432

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I need to know all possible fields that can generate this type of error. For example, TIFF images get different errors. = /